# Dplyr/tidyverse: rename_at `.funs` must contain one renaming function, not 4

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following test data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  g1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  g2 = c(a, a, a, b, b),
  a = sample(5),
  b = sample(5)
)
```

I would like to write a function that summarises grouped columns with a mean and I wish I could have the resulting columns prefixed with "mean_"

```
my_summarise1 <- function(df, group_var, summarise_var) {
df %>%
  group_by_at(.vars = group_var) %>%
  summarise_at(.vars = summarise_var, .funs= mean) %>% 
  rename_at(.vars= summarise_var, .funs=paste('mean_', .))
}
```

Without rename_at line it works fine, but with it throws error:

```
my_summarise1(df, vars(g1,g2),vars(a,b))
```

R responds with

```
 Error: `.funs` must contain one renaming function, not 4
```

How should I effectively prefix the new column names?

Smaller question: is it possible to avoid vars() or quotes arount parameters 
 column names when calling a function?

Knowing these two small things would greatly enhance my code, thank you all very much in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the earlier answer by @docendodiscimus is more succinct, for what it's worth, there are two issues with your code:

1. You need to wrap the `paste` (better: `paste0`) function within `funs`.
2. You need to `ungroup` prior to renaming (see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562819/error-message-when-running-simple-rename-function-in-r)).

A working version of your code looks like this:

```
my_summarise1 <- function(df, group_var, summarise_var) {
    df %>%
        group_by_at(group_var) %>%
        summarise_at(summarise_var, mean) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        rename_at(summarise_var, funs(paste0('mean_', .)))
}

my_summarise1(df, vars(g1, g2), vars(a, b))
## A tibble: 3 x 4
#     g1 g2    mean_a mean_b
#  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1    1. a       2.50   2.50
#2    2. a       4.00   5.00
#3    2. b       3.00   2.50
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Please forgive my small inquiry the same as to the colleague above: , do you think the use of vars(g1,g2) in arguments can be avoided and somehow the vars() it could be done in a function? so that imput would be simply c(g1, g2).

Comment: @JacekKotowski I can’t really add anything do docendodiscimus’ edits. I agree with moving the `vars` statements into the function, and then call `my_summarise1` with e.g. `c("g1","g2")` to make it slightly cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take a simple route, you can use dplyr's way of adding suffixes to the summarised columns:

```
my_summarise1 <- function(df, group_var, summarise_var) {
  df %>%
    group_by_at(.vars = group_var) %>%
    summarise_at(.vars = summarise_var, funs(mean=mean)) 
}


my_summarise1(df, vars(g1,g2), vars(a,b))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   g1 [?]
     g1 g2    a_mean b_mean
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1    1. a       3.50   4.50
2    2. a       4.00   1.00
3    2. b       2.00   2.50
```

In this case, `funs(mean=mean)` tells dplyr to use the suffix `mean` and apply the function `mean`. For clarity, you could use `funs(mysuffix = mean)` to use any different suffix and apply the `mean` function.

---

Re OP's question in comment: you can use the following modification which doesn't require the use of `vars` when calling the function.

```
my_summarise2 <- function(df, group_var, summarise_var) {
  df %>%
    group_by_at(.vars = group_var) %>%
    summarise_at(.vars = summarise_var, funs(mean=mean))
}

my_summarise2(df, c("g1","g2"), c("a","b"))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I wish I could accept two answers.  BTW, do you think the use of vars(g1,g2) in arguments can be avoided and somehow it could be done in a function?

Comment: Thanks. I was puzzled with var type, class... now it looks so much clearer.